# How to link two fetch with the id , in react js and node js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm working on a school projet with nodejs and react Js.

I have To work with en Api To fetch data To do a data viz site.

But at the moment i'm stuck with the fetching of 2 calls of the api.

I have To get the genre id's of the movies and with the id's i ahve to do another api call to get a list of this movies thanks to the genre.

My Api call from the backend :

```
  router.get('/getMovieGenre/:id', cors(), function(req, res) {
    const id = req.params.id
    request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key=' + apiKey + '&with_genres=' + id, { json: true }, function(error, ressponse, body){

        res.send(body)
    });
  });

  router.get('/getMovieGenres', cors(), function(req, res) {

    request('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=' + apiKey , { json: true }, function(error, ressponse, body){

        res.send(body)
    });
  });
```

My reactJs page :

```
  state = {movies: [],genres: []};


  componentDidMount() {
    let id = ""
    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testApi/getMovieGenres")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => this.setState({ genres: res.genres }));

    fetch("http://localhost:9000/testApi/getMovieGenre/" + id)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => this.setState({ movies: res.results }));

  }

  
  render() {

    console.log(this.state.genres)
    let data = []
    this.state.genres.map((genre) => {
      let id ='37'
      data.push({ key: genre.name, data: "this.state.movies" })
    })

  return (
    <>
    <PieChart
    height={500}
    width={500}
    data={data}
  />
  </>
  )
}

}
```

thank you

Comment: Have you tried using postman? You make the Api calls using postman and if you do get a response you can start debugging the front end Api requests.

Comment: Yes the api's call are working on postman and on the front end, but on the first call getMovieGenres I just have the id of the genres, what I want to do it's to recup the genre id and after that make an api call to the getMovieGenre with an array of genre id to get a list of movies

Comment: I think the right process to do that would be to make a call to bring all movies inside componentDidMount and save the response in the state. Then, you map through all the movies in the state to show them to the user, and for each movie you will have a button with the value of the movie.id and once you click that button you make that call to bring one specific movie

Comment: Hm thank you but, i only want a movies list thank to their genre id

    `fetch("http://localhost:9000/testApi/getMovieGenres")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => this.setState({ genres: res.genres }));`